# How to convert flat array of objects with "categories" and "subcategories" to tree with JQ?

Tags: json, categories, data-manipulation, jq

I have a JSON array of objects with groups and subgroups that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Group name": "Elevation", 
    "Subgroup": "Contours", 
    "name": "Contours - Labels"
  }, 
  {
    "Group name": "Elevation", 
    "Subgroup": "Contours", 
    "name": "Contours"
  }, 
  {
    "Group name": "Elevation", 
    "Subgroup": "Cuttings", 
    "name": "Cuttings"
  },
  {
    "Group name": "Framework", 
    "Subgroup": "Reserves", 
    "name": "Reserves"
  }, 
  {
    "Group name": "Framework", 
    "Subgroup": "Indigenous Reserves", 
    "name": "Reserves"
  }, 
  {
    "Group name": "Framework", 
    "Subgroup": "Land Borders", 
    "name": "Mainland"
  }
]
```

I'd like to convert it to a nested structure:

```
[ { type: group, name: Elevation, Items: [ ... ] } ]
```

How do you do this in JQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your expected output is exactly, but this could be done more efficiently.  By parameterizing your grouping function, you could build up your trees in a reusable fashion.

```
def regroup(keyfilter; itemfilter):
    group_by(keyfilter) | map({
        type: "group",
        name: (.[0] | keyfilter),
        items: itemfilter
    })
    ;
regroup(."Group name";
    regroup(.Subgroup;
        map({ name })
    )
)
```

This yields the following results:

```
[
  {
    "type": "group",
    "name": "Elevation",
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "group",
        "name": "Contours",
        "items": [
          { "name": "Contours - Labels" },
          { "name": "Contours" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "group",
        "name": "Cuttings",
        "items": [
          { "name": "Cuttings" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "group",
    "name": "Framework",
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "group",
        "name": "Indigenous Reserves",
        "items": [
          { "name": "Reserves" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "group",
        "name": "Land Borders",
        "items": [
          { "name": "Mainland" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "group",
        "name": "Reserves",
        "items": [
          { "name": "Reserves" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Functions are very powerful, you should try to utilize it more.  Hopefully this shows just how powerful it can be.

Comment: Ah, that is more elegant. Also didn't think of building up the objects rather than removing the unwanted attributes. (In reality there are a couple more fields but I think your approach is still better.)

Comment: This approach would work well, even if there are more fields, just as long as you pick out the fields to keep (or the ones to remove) at the very end. It should keep it more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

This did the job:

```
def subgroups:
group_by(."Subgroup")|
map({
  "type": "group", 
  "name": .[0]."Subgroup", 
  "items": (map(del(.Subgroup)))
});

group_by(."Group name")|
map({
  "type": "group", 
  "name": .[0]."Group name", 
  "items": (subgroups2|map(del(."Group name")))
})
```

It's just the same process twice:

1. `group_by` to sort the outer items on "group name"
2. For each of those groups, construct an object whose name is taken from the first item, and whose items are...
3. Passed through to a function that repeats 1 and 2, and removes the grouping field.